# Pandas Column Value Replacement confusing behaviour.

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, 'metrospot', with a Postal Code column and I want to remove the space in postal code. The below does not alter the dataframe:

```
metrospot['Postal Code'] = metrospot['Postal Code'].replace(" ","")
```

But the below code will:

```
metrospot['Postal Code'] = metrospot['Postal Code'] + "foo"
```

I had to resort to butchery like this to proceed:

```
for i,j in zip(metrospot['Postal Code'],range(len(metrospot))):
    i = i.replace(" ","")
    metrospot.loc[j,'Postal Code']=i
```

What is the correct way to do this and why does the above behaviour happen? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `replace` on the Series object.  This is not the string `replace` method but a [pandas method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) that replaces entire values.  So if any of the values in your column were `" "` (i.e., a cell in the DataFrame contained just a single space and that's it), it would be replaced with an empty string.

If you want to use *string* replacement, use the `str` attribute:

```
metrospot['Postal Code'] = metrospot['Postal Code'].str.replace(" ","")
```